# Magneto 2.4 Recaptcha loads before the form

Tags: magento2.4

I am using magento 2.4.1 and having issue with the recaptcha module. The recaptcha load on the page before the form does. Can anyone suggest some solution to this. I tried loading the script first but still experiencing the same issue. Any ideas what’s the workaround or possible solution.

Comment: Add code how the script is added & script code also in question.

Comment: Which recaptcha module you are working?

Comment: I am using the default - Magento_recaptcha.